# Setting spleen font as console font permanently

Tags: command-line, fonts

I've installed `fonts-spleen` and run `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to change my console font but there is no option for spleen. The spleen fonts are installed in `/usr/share/consolefonts/` with terminus fonts and the rest.

Not sure what else I can report. I'm currently using a `setfont` statement in my `.zprofile` and that works fine. I just wanted a permanent solution.

Thanks.

Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 0):

The console font is loaded at startup by `setupcon`.  However, there appears to be a bug that prevents the font from loading.

```
setfont: ERROR kdfontop.c:232 put_font_kdfontop: ioctl(DKFONTOP): Operation not permitted
```

Until the problem is resolved, you will have to continue using `setfont [filename]`.

Potentially relevant bug reports:

- Ubuntu: [Console/VT font is (randomly) not set (sometimes) on some machines. Stuck with the default VGA BIOS font.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/console-setup/+bug/433897) (2009)
- Debian: [console-setup w/ systemd forgets font setting](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=759657) (2014)

---

When `setupcon` is fixed, you should be able to change the font by editing `/etc/default/console-setup`:

- Comment out `FONTFACE` and `FONTSIZE`.
- Look up font filename in `/usr/share/consolefonts`)
- Add a line with `FONT=[filename]`:

  ```
  FONT='spleen-32x64.psfu.gz'
  ```